# Simultaneous diagonalization of two matrices if one does not has $n$ independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a small confusion. Suppose there are two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ does not has $n$ independent eigenvectors. The $A$ is not diagonalizable. But $A$ and $B$ commute and I can find a matrix that diagonalizes $B$. Doesn't this violate that $A$ is diagonalizable because the same matrix also diagonalizes $A$ which diagonalizes $B$.

Two such matrices are:

$A$
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$B$
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: The problem is that A is not diagonalizable but the fact that A commutes with B allows me to diagonalize A using the matrix which diagonalizes B.

Comment: But your $A$ has three independent eigenvectors. Why did you say it didn't?

Comment: Oh.. You mean even if the rank of a 3x3 matrix is less than 3, still it can have 3 eigenvectors.

Comment: If the rank of an $n\times n$ matrix is $n-k$, that just gives us $k$ independent eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $0$: the basis of the nullspace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this..

Comment: real symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable. They are also congruence diagonalizable, in that there is a real matrix $P$ with $\det P = 1$ and $P^T A P = D$ is diagonal. The diagonal entries of $D$ will not usually be eigenvalues of $A,$ but do obey Sylvester Inertia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, matrices $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalizable (and both have $n$ independent eigenvectors), so it's not an instance of the thing you're describing:

- $A$ has eigenvector $(1,0,1)$ to the eigenvalue $2$, and eigenvectors $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,-1)$ to the eigenvalue $0$.
- $B$ has eigenvector $(1,-2,-1)$ to the eigenvalue $-1$, eigenvector $(1,1,-1)$ to the eigenvalue $2$, and eigenvector $(1,0,1)$ to the eigenvalue $3$.

(Also, since $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric in this example, we know in advance that they should be diagonalizable.)

But in general, no: just because $A$ commutes with $B$ and $B$ is diagonalizable, doesn't mean that $A$ is diagonalizable (in the same basis that diagonalizes $B$, or otherwise). For instance, any matrix (diagonalizable or otherwise) commutes with the zero matrix and the identity matrix.

Also, the Jordan form of a matrix lets us write it as $D + N$ in some basis, where $D$ is diagonal, $N$ is nilpotent (and therefore not diagonalizable in general) and $D$ commutes with $N$, giving us a whole slew of counterexamples.

Comment: The eigenvalues are 2 and 0 with multiplicity 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.